# Property transfer in SOAP UI using xpath

Tags: automated-testing, tools, soapui

I am using SOAP UI open source. In this version we don't have the option to create xpath like in pro version so I created the xpath using different tool and tried to transfer properties in my test cases. But SOAP UI is unable to locate the properties. How can I transfer the properties using xpath in SOAP UI?

### Here is my XML and the xpaths...

SOAP Request#1

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:rad="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Radixx.ConnectPoint.Request" xmlns:rad1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Radixx.ConnectPoint.Security.Request">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:RetrieveSecurityToken>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:RetrieveSecurityTokenRequest>
            <rad:CarrierCodes>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <rad:CarrierCode>
                  <rad:AccessibleCarrierCode>FZ</rad:AccessibleCarrierCode>
               </rad:CarrierCode>
            </rad:CarrierCodes>
            <rad1:LogonID>qwere</rad1:LogonID>
            <rad1:Password>123123</rad1:Password>
         </tem:RetrieveSecurityTokenRequest>
      </tem:RetrieveSecurityToken>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Rsponse#1

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <RetrieveSecurityTokenResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <RetrieveSecurityTokenResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Radixx.ConnectPoint.Security.Response" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Exceptions xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Radixx.ConnectPoint.Exceptions">
               <b:ExceptionInformation.Exception>
                  <b:ExceptionCode>0</b:ExceptionCode>
                  <b:ExceptionDescription>Successful Transaction</b:ExceptionDescription>
                  <b:ExceptionSource>RetrieveSecurityToken</b:ExceptionSource>
                  <b:ExceptionLevel>Success</b:ExceptionLevel>
               </b:ExceptionInformation.Exception>
            </a:Exceptions>
            <a:SecurityToken>8bbd61ca-a976-417a-ab4e-04911be12468</a:SecurityToken>
         </RetrieveSecurityTokenResult>
      </RetrieveSecurityTokenResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

SOAP Request #2

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:rad="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Radixx.ConnectPoint.Request" xmlns:rad1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Radixx.ConnectPoint.TravelAgents.Request">
      <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:LoginTravelAgent>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:LoginTravelAgentRequest>
            <rad:SecurityGUID>ec800955-a52c-4267-bbfd-e3b473727307</rad:SecurityGUID>
            <rad:CarrierCodes>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <rad:CarrierCode>
                  <rad:AccessibleCarrierCode>FZ</rad:AccessibleCarrierCode>
               </rad:CarrierCode>
            </rad:CarrierCodes>
            <rad1:IATANumber>222222</rad1:IATANumber>
            <rad1:UserName>apipml</rad1:UserName>
            <rad1:Password>test</rad1:Password>
         </tem:LoginTravelAgentRequest>
      </tem:LoginTravelAgent>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

xpath for property transfer from SOAP RESPONSE1 to SOAP REQUEST2

property name- security.token

Xpath#1

declare namespace s = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 /s:Envelope/s:Body/RetrieveSecurityTokenResponse/RetrieveSecurityTokenResult/a:SecurityToken

Xpath#2

declare namespace s = declare namespace ns1= "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 s: soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/tem:LoginTravelAgent/tem:LoginTravelAgentRequest/rad:SecurityGUID

Comment: Can you post your XML and XPath?

Comment: yes , i am uploading the xml and the xpath

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it.

Looks like you made a trivial mistake in the `xpath`.

Here is how the test case is defined with following test step names.

1. Soap Request Test step named as `Test Request`
2. Property Transfer Test step
3. Second Soap Request Test step named as `Test Request2`

Here is how `Property Transfer` test step is defined.
Added a property using by clicking on `+`, and named it `id` which you would see on the left side and also in the botton once result is evaluated which is also marked.

**Source** : `Test Request` and Property : `Response` - What it means is that reading first test step and I want to select the given `xpath` on the Response

**Xpath** : `//*:RetrieveSecurityTokenResponse/*:RetrieveSecurityTokenResult/*:SecurityToken`

**Target** : `Test Request2` and Property : `Request` - It means that the evaluated xpath value should be updated from source to target xpath.

**Xpath** : `//*:LoginTravelAgent/*:LoginTravelAgentRequest/*:SecurityGUID`

Here is how it appears:
[image]

Comment: thnx so much rao for such a detailed ans...

Comment: @Tester, appreciate if you accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do it without a namespace, like this:

```
    //*[local-name()='RetrieveSecurityTokenResponse']/*[local-name()='RetrieveSecurityTokenResult']/*[local-name()='SecurityToken']/text()
```